# Looping through radiobutton group

Tags: javascript, for-loop, radio-button

I have the following javascript function. Basically what it does is that it checks a group of radio buttons and if it finds one checkec a value would be set in a particular textbox.

For some reason it is not going through the for loop.

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    document.getElementById('<%= position.ClientID%>').value = location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    var i;
    var checked = false;
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("DynamicRadioButton");  
    for (i = 2; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            var text = document.getElementsByName("DynamicTextBox");
            text[i - 2].value = location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because ihave two static textboxes and all the rest are dynamic and i want to have only one group of radiobuttons all the textboxes.

Comment: How have you established that it's not going through the `for` loop? Have you tried logging inside the loop? Are you getting any console errors? There's not really enough information in your question.

Comment: I have tried using alert, but nothing has popped up.

Comment: We don't know when this code runs, or what the HTML markup looks like, or anything else that could lead to an explanation of the issue. Do you have your browser's developer console open? If not, then be sure to open it and look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jsfiddle, this code does go to the loop. Your problem must be somewhere else:

```
function loop() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("DynamicRadioButton");  
    for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        alert('looping radio ' + i);
    }
};

<input type="radio" name="DynamicRadioButton">radio1</input>
<input type="radio" name="DynamicRadioButton">radio2</input>
<input type="button" value="Loop" onclick="loop()"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/txQVv/1/

Comment: I am doing alert just after the for loop and nothing is being shown. @gerrytan

Comment: Yes but this shows you such code does go into the loop, contrary to what you mention above "For some reason it is not going through the for loop". Please do not utilize SO crowd to debug your code, ask specific technical question